# TransporterFleet speed curve calculation unclear (deceleration)

Tags: kinematics

The deceleration path in default the default TransporterFleet block is shorter than that of a linear kinematic model with constant deceleration and linear speed curve. This leads to a quicker transport cycle time, compared to a linear kinematic model. It is unclear how exactly the speed curve is calcualted - which is what I would like to understand better.

In below example I tested the speed curve and distance curve of default TransporterFleet block in AnyLogic. The loading, moving, and unloading cycle should take 100 sec with a linear kinematic model, but it takes less than that - due to shorter deceleration path. How is deceleration calculated in the TransporterFleet?

[simulated speed and distance curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACn4R.jpg)

Here are some more examples, with different max speeds and decelerations. In that case the deceleration path is even shorter relative to a linear kinematic model with constant deceleration.

[shorter deceleration path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j7aL.jpg)